# How to omit obsolete fields while forcing "false" boolean values being present in JSON serialisation?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm working with JSON serializer from NewtonSoft.

I have lots of field I would like to omit in the final JSON. In order to do so, I use the following JsonSerializerSettings:

```
string temp;
JsonSerializerSettings js = new JsonSerializerSettings();
js.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
temp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(existing_root, Formatting.Indented, js);
```

This is working fine: all obsolete fields are indeed omitted.

However, I have a boolean field of which I would like to see the value (which is false), but I don't know how to do this. I started as follows:

```
[JsonProperty("DIAGNOSTICS")]
public bool DIAGNOSTICS { get; set; }
```

(I find it normal that this gets omitted, seen the settings.)

Then I tried the following in order to force its presence:

```
[JsonProperty("DIAGNOSTICS")]
public bool DIAGNOSTICS { get; set; } = true;
```

(I thought, by changing the default value to `true`, the real value (`false`) would not be omitted anymore, but I was wrong: the field still gets omitted from the json.)

Does anybody know a way to say to the seraliser:

- "*Don't omit that particular field?*", or:
- "*Don't omit boolean values which are false?*"

(I would prefer the first solution, if possible)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just be able to change your `JsonProperty` attribute to this:

```
[JsonProperty("DIAGNOSTICS", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/YVR13687)

Comment: @Dominique Indeed. I find a lot of documentation to be lacking unless you're doing the general thing, unfortunately. You can see all the configuration options that `JsonProperty` has [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm).

Comment: I also found that `[JsonProperty(nameof(DIAGNOSTICS), DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]` works as well in addition to `.Populate` as you stated.

Comment: @DekuDesu The difference between those two is in deserializing: `Populate` will also set the property when deserializing, `Include` will not

Comment: @Charlieface, you're absolutely correct, however, in this particular use case his auto property will always have a default value assigned when the type(bool) is initialized by the CLR since it's a boolean.