# How to add a (possibly empty) JSON property, based on a condition?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, properties, json.net

Yesterday, I needed to add a property in a JSON file, I've done this using `DefaultHandling`, as mentioned in [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68527116):

```
[JsonProperty("DIAGNOSTICS", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
public bool DIAGNOSTICS { get; set; }
```

Now I'm dealing with a more complicated situation:

Excerpt of my source code:

```
[JsonProperty("NAME")]
public string NAME { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("i1.ENABLE")]
public bool i1ENABLE { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("i2.ENABLE")]
public bool i2ENABLE { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("i3ENABLE")]
public bool i3ENABLE { get; set; }
...
```

Desired JSON result:

```
"NAME": "i1",
"i1.ENABLE": false, /* i2.ENABLE and i3.ENABLE are not shown */
...
"NAME": "i2",
"i2.ENABLE": false, /* i1.ENABLE and i3.ENABLE are not shown */
...
"NAME": "i3",
"i3.ENABLE": false, /* i1.ENABLE and i2.ENABLE are not shown */
...
```

So my question is, is this possible (pseudo-code) and in case yes, how?

```
[JsonProperty("i1.ENABLE", DefaultValueHandling = (IF(NAME=="i1") THEN DefaultValueHandling.Populate))]
public bool i1ENABLE { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("i2.ENABLE", DefaultValueHandling = (IF(NAME=="i2") THEN DefaultValueHandling.Populate))]
public bool i2ENABLE { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("i3.ENABLE", DefaultValueHandling = (IF(NAME=="i3") THEN DefaultValueHandling.Populate))]
public bool i3ENABLE { get; set; }
```

**Edit** (after first answer from [Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7313891/laurent))

My serialisation code is the following:

```
JsonSerializerSettings js = new JsonSerializerSettings();
js.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
string temp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, js);
```

In case it can't be done in the property declaration, can it be done here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize Property, but Do Not Deserialize Property in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731320/serialize-property-but-do-not-deserialize-property-in-json-net)

Comment: @masoud: that other question does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the [Conditional Property Serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm) of json.net

```
class CC {
  [JsonProperty("NAME")]
  public string NAME { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("i1.ENABLE")]
  public bool i1ENABLE { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("i2.ENABLE")]
  public bool i2ENABLE { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("i3.ENABLE")]
  public bool i3ENABLE { get; set; }

  public bool ShouldSerializei1ENABLE() {
    bool r = NAME == "i1";
    return r;
  }

  public bool ShouldSerializei2ENABLE() {
    bool r = NAME == "i2";
    return r;
  }

  public bool ShouldSerializei3ENABLE() {
    bool r = NAME == "i3";
    return r;
  }

}
```

So a property will only be serialized if `ShouldSerialize[PropertyName]()` returns `true`;

See also [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1yOf5r)

**EDIT**

Yes, the `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` in your `JsonSerializerSettings` may indeed have an influence on the result of the serialization. Ie, even if `ShouldSerialize...` returns `true`, a property won't be serialized if it equals to the default value (in this particular case a `bool` will never be serialized, if it's `false` and `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` is set).

So, if you always want to serialize `i1ENABLE` when `NAME` equals `i1`, you have to override the `DefaultValueHandling` for this property.

```
class CC {
  [JsonProperty("NAME")]
  public string NAME { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("i1.ENABLE", DefaultValueHandling=DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
  public bool i1ENABLE { get; set; }

  public bool ShouldSerializei1ENABLE() {
    bool r = NAME == "i1";
    return r;
  }
}
```

So when you serialize as follows

```
JsonSerializerSettings js = new JsonSerializerSettings();
js.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
string temp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, js);
```

the property `i1ENABLE` will *always* be serialized, when `NAME == "i1"` but *never* be serialized when `NAME != "i1"`

`ShouldSerialize...` is probably one of the first filters, that is done during serialization of a property. If it returns `false`, this property is never serialized. But if it returns `true`, there are still other checks. One of them is `DefaultValueHandling`. So if `DefaultValueHandling` is set to `Ignore` a boolean with value `false` won't be serialized, even if `ShouldSerialize...` returns true.

Please see also this [updated fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jLW1jw)

Comment: Ahem, did you copy the code from this answer? I just saw there is a typo in the methods' name. I wrote `ShouldSerialie...` instead of `ShouldSerialize...`  Other than that, no it should not have anything to do with DefaultHandling or anything other. If `ShouldSerialize...` returns false, the property should not be serialized at all

Comment: Yes, I have seen your spelling mistake, but the names of the functions I used were correct (otherwise they would not be catched by the debugger).

Comment: Can you verify with the debugger, that `ShouldSerialize...` indeed returns the correct value

Comment: I have: the return value is indeed `true` in that particular case, and it is `false` for the other cases. So the result should be correct. Is it possible that the issue is caused by the basic `JsonSerializerSettings`, as mentioned in the edit of my question?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought a property was serialized, eventhough it shouldn't. But it's the other way around, the property is still missing, eventhough `ShouldSerialize` returns true. Please see the updatet answer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have conditions in your attributes.
Try setting these conditional default values in regular code instead. (Attributes can only have constant values)

Comment: According to the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher, it should be possible.

Comment: you've just linked a user's page